# White noise being picked up on my computer mic

Tags: audio

I just got a new mic (Floureon BM-800 Condenser Studio Recording Microphone) and starred recording in Audacity. When i play the audio back there is always a white noise that seems to be even louder than my talking. I don't have a stand for it so I just hold it.

Comment: What's a "three prong computer microphone" exactly?

Comment: I took that out I'm sorry. I thought it was my mic but it's not

Comment: Use a power supply surge protector to isolate the background electromagnetic noise

Comment: What's your sound card? How do you provide the necessary phantom power (48V)?

Comment: This question is not about computers, other than you are using Audacity. You will need to tell us more about how you have things connected, your computer, sound card, etc. Otherwise, it seems off topic or needing to be on [Sound Design](http://sound.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think @dirkt is on to something: you probably do not have 48v phantom power supplied on the mic input.

Because of this, the mic is super quiet and that leads you to crank up the gain and volume so you can hear your voice, but this just amplifies the noise also.

http://www.floureon.com/product-g_52.html

> Kindly Note:
>
> 1. This is a Condenser Microphone only work with the device that could provide enough power for it. When connected with desktop computer, the
>      Condenser Microphone could be used alone; When connected with laptop
>      computer, please connect the laptop to electrical outlet, **or use a 48V**
>      **phantom power to get enough power if the sound is not clear and high**
>      **enough**.
> 2. If your device could not provide enough power (When used with Amplifier or Mixer,etc.), **the sound volume recorded might be low**, and
>      please use a extra 48V phantom power adapter to connect it.(phantom
>      power adapter is not included)
> 3. Can not be used with mobile phone and tablet computer.
> 4. If you want better sound effect, a sound card could be used.
> 5. When recording，please put the microphone away from the amplifier to prevent recording noise due to amplifier.

Some sort of audio interface meant for recording is probably a good way to go here by the way.

The microphone has an XLR connector and in some photos, an XLR-to-1/8 inch TRS (tip,ring,sleeve) connector. These are for what is called a balanced connection where the signal is sent over two different wires, each 180 degrees "out of phase" (this might not be technically accurate, but is the way it is commonly phrased).

The receiver inverts one of those signals(?), and then sums this with the other signal. This results in amplification of the recorded info and depresses the noise induced by the cables etc.

This means higher quality and less noise, so if you get an audio interface that can accept a balanced connection and provide 48v phantom power, you will be happier with the result.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_audio

Comment: This mic comes in 2 flavours [& many theoretical manufacturers]. Presumably the XLR version is phantom, the jack version is battery-powered. The OP would need to know for certain which they have. There's already a question on sound design about it - http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/40605/i-have-a-bm-800-mic-that-isnt-working